# Can't permit nested param in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

I've been ripping my hair off with this one. I have read all the doc about Rails 4 integrating strong params and that now everything has to be explicitly whitelisted. But it still won't go through!!!

Here is my setup

#### Models

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :chapters
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :chapters
end

class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
end
```

#### Controller

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def create
    @course = Course.create permitted_params
    respond_with @course
  end

  private

  def permitted_params
    params.require(:course).permit(:name, chapters_attributes: [:title, :content])
  end
end
```

#### JSON from client

```
{
    "course": {
        "chapters": [{
            "title": "qwerty",
            "content": "foobar"
        }],
        "name": "Test course"
    }
}
```

#### Server log

```
Started POST "/json/courses" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-02-24 15:29:44 +0000
Processing by CoursesController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"course"=>{"chapters"=>[{"title"=>"qwerty", "content"=>"foobar"}], "name"=>"Test course"}}
Unpermitted parameters: chapters
Completed 201 Created in 96ms (Views: 52.1ms | ActiveRecord: 4.1ms)
```

Unpermitted params: chapters. I've been staring at this for hours with no avail. I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please tell me its right there and I just forgot some stupid magical param so I can move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is not in the controller or model, but in the JSON sent in the request.

```
Processing by CoursesController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"course"=>{"chapters"=>[{"title"=>"qwerty", "content"=>"foobar"}], "name"=>"Test course"}}
```

should instead be

```
Processing by CoursesController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"course"=>{"chapters_attributes"=>[{"title"=>"qwerty", "content"=>"foobar"}], "name"=>"Test course"}}
```

If you post your view code we can probably track down the issue fairly quickly.

Comment: Oh god! You made me realize I had misspelled one of my other params. I had tried this before and it failed, but it was for another reason and now that I changed it again I saw it was because of that typo! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe you just need to change to 'chapters' in your permitted_params method :

```
def permitted_params
    params.require(:course).permit(:name, chapters: [:title, :content])
end
```

instead of "chapters_attributes"

Comment: Or make the json return `chapters_attributes` ... one way or another, you have a mismatch there.   I think rails nested attributes wants the nested attributes to be `chapters_attributes`

Comment: This does not change the result. It refuses to accept chapters. Besides this is the new convention: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: When I change it to chapters, I get a AssociationTypeMismatch exception.